# image processing library for colour identification

Tags: image-processing, unity-game-engine, qr-code

I am going to use Unity 3D to create a Flood Management game.In the game,I will project a terrain created in Unity and the user will place objects like dams,levees etc.All these objects need to be recognized via a camera using some image processing technique.Any ideas as to how I should go about this?We thought of placing QR codes on these objects, but that wont work as we will have to recognize multiple QR codes from one image which is probably not feasible.Also, are there any other efficient methods

Answer (score 0):

Wow lots of nice ways to do this.
Easiest: Color tracking using colors
Harder but more interesting: Use Vuforia plugin with markers.

Stephane